# I need to host a web application in IIS in Azure, how do I?

Tags: sql-server, azure, iis

I need to host a web application in IIS in Azure, if I take a virtual machine with Windows 2012 standard, how do I install SQL Server? Or is there any other option?

Answer (score 4):

Getting most out of the Azure platform, I would suggest to use [Azure Web Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/)  and  [Azure SQL Databases](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/) for that.

Using VMs only make sense, if you need control over the underlying systems (e.g. OS settings, Advanced SQL Server features like SSRS).

Comment: There is no more Azure SQL Databases just SQL Database on AZURE. There are many situations where using VMs makes sense (if you want to get the most out of your hardware while isolating instances and controlling resources.). I would say that as of now the plurality (and probably majority) of SQL Server production instances are on some kind of VM. Its moving to AWS or AZURE but as of now in the Fortune 100 companies I work with its getting more and more rare that I see SQL Server running directly on machines.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use AZURE make sure you read a little about what you can and cannot do on AZURE. For example there is no SQL Server Agent or global temp tables. I like the requirement that all tables require a clustered index. You may not.

Here are two articles that list some of the differences but these are an incomplete list:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureedu/2016/07/15/what-features-are-not-supported-in-azure-sql-database/

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Azure+SQL+database/143076/

To install SQL Server on Azure follow this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-portal-sql-server-provision